# Почему здесь НЕ пишется раздельно: "Поблекли не успевшие отцвести лесные колокольчики"?

Tags: орфография, частица-не

> Поблекли не успевшие отцвести лесные колокольчики.

Почему в данном предложении НЕ пишется раздельно?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что раздельное написание "не успевшие" никогда не является ошибкой. Сейчас в русском языке имеется тенденция – все чаще и чаще вместо традиционно раздельного встречается слитное написание НЕ с причастиями и наречиями. Но в правила это пока не вошло.

Comment: Совершенно бессодержательное утверждение. Да, всегда или почти всегда можно найти основания для раздельного написания (отрицание возможно почти всегда), но вопрос, правильно ли такое понимание с логической точки зрения. Да автор и не ставит так вопрос. Вопрос почему именно тут раздельное.

Answer (score 0):

Поблекли **не успевшие отцвести** лесные колокольчики.

**Раздельное написание НЕ.**

Глагол "успеть" употребляется с инфинитивом. УСПЕТЬ, 1. с инф. Суметь сделать что-л. в срок, своевременно.

Соответственно, к причастию "успевшие" также всегда относится инфинитив,  а НЕ пишется слитно только с одиночными причастиями.

Слитное написание приставки НЕ встречается, если причастие переходит в существительное: Среди пострадавших есть **неуспевшие спасти** даже носильного платья. [Провинция (1912.03.16) // «Голос Земли», 1912]

**Товарищ Мимоходов!** Может быть, это, конечно, малодушие с моей стороны – оставлять сайт в  ваше личное пользование, но я утешаю себя следующим. Если бы на форуме работали **РОЗЕНТАЛЬ ИЛИ ЗАЛИЗНЯК**, то и они бы после общения с вами **БЕЖАЛИ ОТСЮДА СО ВСЕХ НОГ**, признавшись, **что ничего не смыслят в русском языке.**

Comment: *если причастие переходит в существительное* - откуда такая мысль? Да и пример явно не на субстантивацию причастия. "Среди пострадавших есть пришедшие поздно" - ну какое тут существительное?! Но дело даже не в этом. *Глагол "успеть" употребляется с инфинитивом*. При чем тут раздельное написание?  Вы так просто запутаете человека, а у него русский  может даже и не родной.

Comment: 1) нет. Фактическая ошибка. Правило не так звучит.  2) - a) не всегда. б) не имеет отношения к вопросу. В моем (и вашем) примере - точно нет. Ой, не разглядел. "субстантивированное существительное" - это что за зверь? Масло масляное?!

Comment: >>  *Среди пострадавших есть пришедшие поздно" - ну какое тут существительное?!* @Мимоходов, самое натуральное. Среди пострадавших есть (кто? а не какие) пришедшие поздно. Это подлежащее.

Comment: @Sibylla не могли бы вы пояснить, почему тут однозначно существительное и (самое главное) почему почему вы вообще сделали такой вывод, что только в этом случае "не" пишется слитно?! Это какое-то общее правило? (А как же тогда "непримиримый", "недоказанный"- с любым количеством зависимых слов?) А если это какое-то специфическое свойство этого глагола/причастия, то какое именно? Никто не спорит с раздельным написанием, но обоснование у вас - "оставляет желать".

Comment: @Мимоходов Что за 1) - 2) правило, и "субстантивированное существительное"? Я никак не пойму, из-за чего спор-то разгорелся?

Comment: @Иванов7-й Да это следы старой драки. "субстантивированное существительное" - это Sibylla так изволила выразиться. а 1) и 2) это про зависиимое слово. Sibylla там привела свою версию правила (смешав правило-критерий и признак) ну и свою же версию признака субстантивированности. Но коли удалено, но обсуждать всерьез смысла нет.

Answer (score -1):

Здесь "не успевшие" отрицание, а не новое понятие "неуспевший".

Признаком этого является наличие зависимого слова. У нас это слово "спасти".

*Все цветы отцвели. Поблекли неуспевшие колокольчики.* - тут было бы возможно слитное написание (наряду с раздельным).

Примеры такого написания:

> Младенец был привезен из роддома, заранее купили приданое, но мальчик
>   (несостоявшийся, неуспевший отец) проявлял себя в дальнейшем
>   беззаботно. [Людмила Петрушевская. Детский праздник (1998-1999)]
>   [омонимия не снята] ←…→
>
> А в церкви ― беспрерывные молебны, древний лысый диакон и еще
>   неуспевший искуситься Павел Андреевич так задушевно но привычке поют:
>   «Пресвятая Богородице, спаси нас!» [Митрополит Вениамин (Федченков).
>   На рубеже двух эпох (1940-1950)] [омонимия не снята] ←…→
>
> Но вообще воспитанники занимаются очень прилежно; здесь главная
>   побудительная причина занятий ― нужда: неуспевший воспитанник
>   исключается, и при этом пропадают не только все деньги, которые он
>   платил в конвикт, но он должен еще заплатить тот излишек, который
>   истратила на него казна. [К. Д. Ушинский. Педагогическая поездка по
>   Швейцарии (1862-1863)] [омонимия не снята] ←…

Обратите внимание, что вопреки Sibylla в двух случаях из трех инфинитива при "неуспевший" вообще нет, а о переходе в существительное даже речи не идет.

Comment: С полными формами причастий отрицание не пишется раздельно: ***не обязанный подчиняться***; Здесь ведь инфинитив зависимое слово. Это пример из справочника Лопатина.

Comment: @Серж Чем я-то могу помочь?!  Давай-те уже по существу. Я прелдлагаю писать в данном случае не слитно?! Нет. Вы объяснили, почему в моих примерах написано слитно?! Нет. Если вам непонятно напирчсанное у Лопатина, задайте отдельный вопрос. Спасибо за интерес к моему ответу.

Comment: @Мимоходов, вы бы ещё фрагменты школьных сочинений привели. "Еще неуспевший искуситься" – за это нынче двойки ставят.

Comment: @Мимоходов, вы утверждаете, что инфинитив не является зависимым словом в рассматриваемым примере. Я вас правильно понял?

Comment: @Серж Вы поняли совершенно неверно.